# Outer merge on a dataframes within a dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, merge

I am new to python and have been searching the web for a solution to this problem but have not found any. I have a dictionary of pandas dataframes where the key is a 'Year' and the values are pandas dataframes of that year. Here is the example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

##Creating Dataframes
data1_2018 =[[1,2018,80], [2,2018,70]]
data2_2018 = [[1,2018,77], [3,2018,62]]
data3_2018 = [[1,2018,82], [2,2018,88], [4,2018,66]]

data1_2017 = [[1,2017,80], [5,2017,70]]
data2_2017 = [[1,2017,77], [3,2017,62]]
data3_2017 = [[1,2017,50], [2,2017,52], [4,2017,51]]

df1_2018 = pd.DataFrame(data1_2018, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_1'])
df2_2018 = pd.DataFrame(data2_2018, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_2'])
df3_2018 = pd.DataFrame(data3_2018, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_3'])


df1_2017 = pd.DataFrame(data1_2017, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_1'])
df2_2017 = pd.DataFrame(data2_2017, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_2'])
df3_2017 = pd.DataFrame(data3_2017, columns = ['ID', 'Year', 'Score_3'])

###Creating list of all dataframes
all_df_list = [df1_2018,df2_2018,df3_2018,df1_2017,df2_2017,df3_2017]
```

I have chosen to start with a list with all the dataframes because that is how the data is imported in my real problem. Once I have the list of dataframes I created a dictionary of those dataframes.

```
yearly_dfs = defaultdict(list)
####Loop for creating dict with keys being years and values being dfs for that year
for df in all_df_list:
    for yr, yr_df in df.groupby('Year'):
        yearly_dfs[yr].append(yr_df)
```

Now, my question is.. can you loop through each group a dataframes and merge them together with an outer merge by 'ID'. The desired output would be a list or dictionary with only one dataframe per year. Here is what the desired result would look like for each year:

```
desired_output_2018 = df1_2018.merge(df2_2018, how = 'outer', on = ['ID', 'Year']).merge(df3_2018, how = 'outer', on = ['ID', 'Year']) 
desired_output_2017 = df1_2017.merge(df2_2017, how = 'outer', on = ['ID', 'Year']).merge(df3_2017, how = 'outer', on = ['ID', 'Year'])

print(desired_output_2018)
   ID  Year  Score_1  Score_2  Score_3
0   1  2018     80.0     77.0     82.0
1   2  2018     70.0      NaN     88.0
2   3  2018      NaN     62.0      NaN
3   4  2018      NaN      NaN     66.0

print(desired_output_2017)
   ID  Year  Score_1  Score_2  Score_3
0   1  2017     80.0     77.0     50.0
1   5  2017     70.0      NaN      NaN
2   3  2017      NaN     62.0      NaN
3   2  2017      NaN      NaN     52.0
4   4  2017      NaN      NaN     51.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 'Year' & 'ID', with agg function [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), then use in a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) with `grouby` 'Year':

```
df_all = (pd.concat(all_df_list, sort=False)
          .groupby(['ID', 'Year']).first().reset_index())

df_years = {yr: df for yr, df in df_all.groupby('Year')}
```

Access like:

```
df_years[2017]

   ID  Year  Score_1  Score_2  Score_3
0   1  2017     80.0     77.0     50.0
2   2  2017      NaN      NaN     52.0
4   3  2017      NaN     62.0      NaN
6   4  2017      NaN      NaN     51.0
8   5  2017     70.0      NaN      NaN

df_years[2018]

  ID  Year  Score_1  Score_2  Score_3
1   1  2018     80.0     77.0     82.0
3   2  2018     70.0      NaN     88.0
5   3  2018      NaN     62.0      NaN
7   4  2018      NaN      NaN     66.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. For some reason when I run the code I get the error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: there must be a `list` hidden in amongst the `DataFrames` in `all_df_list`. What is `print([type(x) for x in all_df_list])` ? See if you can find the offending object

Comment: `[x for x in all_df_list if isinstance(x, list)]` may also help track it down..?

Comment: Thank you! It was my own user error, your code worked great!